# Should this question have the jealousy tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

In this question,

[As a woman, how to avoid angry stares from other people's wives or girlfriends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/as-a-woman-how-to-avoid-angry-stares-from-other-peoples-wives-or-girlfriends),

I added the new jealousy tag.  Is this correct to do?

Based on the context of the question, it would seem that the angry stares from the women stem from jealousy, and the jealousy tag says that it's for situations influenced by jealousy, whether felt by the OP or someone else.

Comment: Why not? I don't really see the point of asking about this on meta.

Comment: Are you not answering your own question here? "it would seem that the angry stares from the women stem from jealousy"..."the jealousy tag says that it's for situations influenced by jealousy, whether felt by the OP **or someone else**"

Comment: We don't know for certain whether the angry stares are because of jealously, though - some answerers write that, but the OP doesn't explicitly say it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're about to tag a few questions at a time, it's not necessary to ask on meta. If you have the privileges and site experience to add a tag, you may do so. And others will see the post and rollback the edit if it's deemed absolutely unworthy of a tag.

In this particular question, it sure can have the jealousy tag. The question meets the criteria listed under that tag description: "For questions about situations influenced by feelings of jealousy, whether felt by you or someone else."